# Do unnecessary changes cause ship malfunction?

Tags: spaceteam

In Spaceteam, when a session is over, there are credits with data, including the number of unnecessary changes made.

I feel that it is the case, but I am not sure: Do unnecessary changes cause the ship to malfunction more?

Comment: I *think* they just waste your precious time (and then it rubs that in during the credits) rather than cause more malfunctions, but my gut feeling is not worthy of an answer.

Comment: Judging from recent play, it seems that unnecessary changes do cause ship malfunction.